# text widget tkinter copy images options

Tags: python, image, text, tkinter

I'm creating a simple GUI where I need to be able at the end to copy an image from a text widget, I'm able to copy text but I can't copy the image, is there a way to do that?  here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\ElchananPeres\\Desktop\\capture222.PNG")
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
text.image_create(END,image=photo)
root.mainloop()
```